# No data except fo username and email is saved

Tags: python, django

When I go to the admin interface all the fields are threre but none of them have any data except for username and email after i submit the form. Any help?

```
class SignupFormExtra(userena.forms.SignupForm):

first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
gender = forms.CharField(max_length=3, required=False)
phone = forms.CharField(label=(u'Phone Number'),max_length=10, required=False)
cell = forms.CharField(label=(u'Cell Number'),max_length=10)
address = forms.CharField(label=(u'Dental Practice Address'),max_length=50, required=False)



def save(self):

    self.cleaned_data['username'] = self.cleaned_data['email']

    user = super(SignupFormExtra, self).save()


    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    #user.birth_date = self.cleaned_data['birth_date']
    user.gender = self.cleaned_data['gender']
    user.phone = self.cleaned_data['phone']
    user.cell = self.cleaned_data['cell']
    user.address = self.cleaned_data['address']
    user.save()

    return user
```

Comment: Not sure what you want us to tell you if we can't see the important bits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SignupForm.save` returns a `contrib.auth.User` object which doesn't have `gender`, `phone`,  `cell` or `address` fields. My guess would be these are on your profile model but in the code you have shown this isn't where you are attempting to save them.

Answer (score 0):

That problem would be in your models.py module not in forms.

Answer (score 0):

userena.forms.SignupForm creates a UserenaSignup, that model doesn't have the fields you specify.

see: https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/models.py#L39